# inject Action into UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, dependency-properties

My View Contains a `Button` and a `UserControl`. The `UserControl` also contains a `Button`. Both, Button1 in my View and Button2 in my `UserControl` should call the same method in the ViewModel.

[image: ViewViewModelUserControl]

Therefore I need to 'inject' (don't know how to call it) the `RelayCommand` into the `UserControl`. I thought it would be easy with dependency properties but i can't get it to work.

What i tried:

The `UserControl` contains a dependency property which is set in the XAML Code of the View containing the `UserControl`:

UserControl Code:

```
public const string LoadDataCommandPropertyName = "LoadDataCommand";
public Action LoadDataCommand
{
    get
    {
        return (Action)GetValue(LoadDataCommandProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(LoadDataCommandProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadDataCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    LoadDataCommandPropertyName,
    typeof(Action),
    typeof(GridViewPersistenceController),
    new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

View Xaml Code: (usage of the dp in the UserControl)

```
<customControls:MyUserControl Grid.Column="1" 
                              x:Name="RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl" 
                              GridControl="{Binding ElementName=RadGridView}"
                              LoadDataCommand="{Binding ActionTest}"
                              />
```

The LoadDataCommand from the UserControl is bound to this property in the ViewModel

```
private const string ActionTestPropertyName = "ActionTest";
private Action actionTest;
public Action ActionTest
{
    get
    {
        return this.actionTest;
    }

    set
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanging(ActionTestPropertyName);
        this.actionTest = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(ActionTestPropertyName);
    }
}
```

The ActionTest property is initialized in the Constructor of the ViewModel

```
public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.ActionTest = new Action(this.LoadData);
        }
```

The visual studio output window also gave me a binding error (which i don't understand)

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ActionTest' property not found on 'object' ''MyUserControl'
>   (Name='RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl')'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ActionTest; DataItem='MyUserControl'
>   (Name='RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl'); target element is
>   'MyUserControl' (Name='RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl'); target
>   property is 'LoadDataCommand' (type 'Action')

I found a workaround which is working but i don't like it. I set the LoadDataCommand in LoadedEvent of View codebehind. It looks messy to me and i feel i missed some important concepts.

```
//TODO: Dirty coding, fix me
    private void MyView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl.LoadDataCommand = new Action((this.DataContext as MyViewModel).LoadData);
    }
```

Questions:

- How do i pass a `Command`/`Action` defined in the ViewModel into a UserControl using xaml code in the View?
- Why is my current approach with bindings not working?
- Am I missing some fundamental concepts? (Could i archieve this easier with delegates? (I tried..))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As evident from the error:

> 'ActionTest' property not found on 'object' ''MyUserControl'
>   (Name='RadGridViewSettingsPersistenceControl')'

**binding engine is searching for property in control and not in your ViewModel**. (by default it searches for property in DataContext of control and i suspect you have set DataContext of control to itself somewhere in your code)

Use *RelativeSource to get DataContext of your UserControl* which will be your ViewModel.

```
LoadDataCommand="{Binding DataContext.ActionTest,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                           AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

---

Also instead of creating DP of type `Action`, use `ICommand` and create ICommand in your ViewModel and bind to it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Why should I prefer ICommand implementations (such as RelayCommand) over Action?

Comment: Suppose you want to disable your button on some condition. With `ICommand` in place you can simply write your validation code in `CanExecute` of command but with `Action` approach you have to write additional logic.

Comment: Sir, you earned yourself a green tick.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use a *attached* dependency property. Below is an example:

`AttachedDependencyProperty`

```
public static class UserControlExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionProperty;

    public static void SetAction(DependencyObject DepObject, ICommand value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(ActionProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetAction(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (ICommand)DepObject.GetValue(ActionProperty);
    }

    static UserControlExtension()
    {
        ActionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Action",
                                                            typeof(ICommand),
                                                            typeof(UserControlExtension));
    }
}
```

`TestViewModel`

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    private ICommand _testButtonCommand = null;

    public ICommand TestButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_testButtonCommand == null)
            {
                _testButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.TestButton(), null);
            }

            return _testButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    private void TestButton() 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test command execute");
    }
}
```

`MainWindow` as `View`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TestViewModel x:Key="TestVM" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource TestVM}">
    <local:TestUserControl x:Name="TestUserControl"
                           AttachedProperties:UserControlExtension.Action="{Binding TestButtonCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

`UserControl`

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="TestButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Content="TestContent"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                              Path=(AttachedProperties:UserControlExtension.Action)}" />        
</Grid>
```

Sample project is available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!117&authkey=!AMQtGbontmDua4Q&ithint=file,.zip).

Comment: AttachedProperties are fairly new to me, thanks for sharing. In this case I prefer the solution from @Rohit Vats but I will keep AttachedProperties in mind. I'm pretty sure they become useful some day.

Comment: @Joel: I share your sample project, I hope it will be helpful to you.